# 'error during type inferencing' in eclipse when developing node.js application

Tags: eclipse, node.js

I'm developing node in eclipse, and i'm getting into some really weird error, that gets thrown every few minutes in the 'error log':

Message:

```
'error during type inferencing'
```

Stack Trace:

```
'java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferredAttribute.<init>(InferredAttribute.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferredType.addAttribute(InferredType.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferEngine.populateType(InferEngine.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferEngine.handlePotentialType(InferEngine.java:925)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferEngine.visit(InferEngine.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.DelegateASTVisitor.visit(DelegateASTVisitor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.traverse(Assignment.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferEngine.doInfer(InferEngine.java:1772)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.inferTypes(Parser.java:7093)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.accept(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForBinding(LookupEnvironment.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2105)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:1876)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferredType.resolveType(InferredType.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.bindArguments(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.buildMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:209)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.buildFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.buildFieldsAndMethods(CompilationUnitScope.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.accept(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForBinding(LookupEnvironment.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2105)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:1876)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferredType.resolveType(InferredType.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.resolveVarType(LocalDeclaration.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope$DeclarationVisitor.visit(CompilationUnitScope.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.LocalDeclaration.traverse(LocalDeclaration.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.buildTypeBindings(CompilationUnitScope.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.buildTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.accept(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForBinding(LookupEnvironment.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2105)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:1876)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferredType.resolveType(InferredType.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.bindArguments(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope$DeclarationVisitor.visit(CompilationUnitScope.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.buildTypeBindings(CompilationUnitScope.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.buildTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.accept(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForBinding(LookupEnvironment.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2105)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:1876)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.infer.InferredType.resolveType(InferredType.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodScope.createMethod(MethodScope.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope$DeclarationVisitor.visit(CompilationUnitScope.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.traverse(MethodDeclaration.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.buildTypeBindings(CompilationUnitScope.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.buildTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.accept(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForBinding(LookupEnvironment.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:2105)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getBinding(Scope.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.findBinding(SingleNameReference.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.resolveType(SingleNameReference.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleNameReference.resolveType(SingleNameReference.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.resolveType(FunctionExpression.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Assignment.resolveType(Assignment.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler.process(JavaReconciler.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:206)'
```

It's important to mention that it doesn't affect on running the application. I can run it without any problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same one.

Answer (score 0):

If the error is still there as of Nodeclipse 0.7,
raise an issue on https://github.com/nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/

and give some information needed as mentioned on http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support